# How did my script run out of memory and execution time at the same time?

Tags: php

I knew I was going to run out of something, since I was running a very long task. That's not the problem.

I am just curious, how did I get both errors at the same time?

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 71 bytes) in...

--

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in Unknown
>   on line 0

Shouldn't the first "fatal" error halt execution? I am running APC and php 5.2.6.

EDIT:
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hTPi.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure they are from the same script? Or perhaps the maximum execution time error triggers another action, which causes the memory size error (through register_shutdown_function())

Comment: Can you reproduce it?

Comment: @periklis: not possible. max exec time is fatal and kills the script immediately. allowing MORE code to run would simply allow the limit to be bypassed. ditto for max memory.

Comment: It also should have raised an End Of Lifecycle Error because you are using a dead version of PHP.

Comment: While this is an interesting issue, the question is worthless without any code at all, as all we can do now is guessing.

Comment: Could you answer @WaleedKhan's question above?

Comment: @MarcB: I think that register_shutdown_function executes for max_execution_time errors (just tried it, http://pastebin.com/ypZimctv, it's also reported in a comment in the docs, http://gr2.php.net/register_shutdown_function)

Answer (score 4):

It *might* be that you're running into a race-condition here.

It basically works for example triggering a FATAL in the shutdown function for the memory and a FATAL for the timeout earlier triggering the shutdown function:

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
    # consume all memory
    echo "break my pain\n";
    $a = ['hello'];
    while($a[] = $a);
});

set_time_limit(1);
while(1) usleep(100);
```

It also works the other way round, first triggering the FATAL for the memory, then the FATAL for the timeout in the shutdown function:

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
    set_time_limit(1);
    while(1) usleep(100);
});

ini_set('memory_limit', '1');
$a = array_fill(0, 1024, 'hello');
while($a[] = $a);
```

This does not yet 100% explain what happens inside Codeigniter, however I'd say the query takes too long therefore after returning triggering the execution time limit as well. This is somewhat hard to reproduce because of your older PHP version. If I now eval PHP code, I get the message that the code was eval'ed and in which line I find that eval command (PHP 5.4). Try to reproduce with PHP 5.4 to gain more information. You will also greatly benefit from the speed improvements we've seen since PHP 5.2. You're missing a lot.

*Earlier:*

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in Unknown on line 0

This smells like a startup error.

What has triggered your first error is hard to say, you cutted it off. Either you have got eval'ed code here which might have been handled partly a-part via APC you could see two fatal errors in the same script.

However, try without APC if you can reproduce it. If you still can, please report it in the PHP bugtracker.

If you can't, please report the problem with the APC bugtracker.

*Edit:* Just seeing PHP 5.2.6, you might need to report and fix it your own though ;) - Try to reproduce with the current stable PHP version as well then.

Answer (score 0):

One way that this can happen, is if you have a register_shutdown_function:

```
<?php
register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction');
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_errors", true);
ini_set("memory_limit", "5M");
ini_set("max_execution_time", 1);

for ($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++) {
    $val[] = rand();
}

function shutDownFunction() {
    echo "executed";
    for ($i=0;$i<100000000;$i++) {
        $val = rand();
    }
}
```

Outputs the same with what you got:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 5242880 bytes exhausted (tried to
> allocate 524288 bytes) in
> /home/periklis/workspace/build_script/test.php on line 8
>
> executed
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 1 second exceeded in
> /home/periklis/workspace/build_script/test.php on line 13